# Quantlib: library not found for -lboost_thread on OSX

Tags: macos, boost, quantlib

I'm following this instructions to install Quantlib on Macosx.
When I lunch the "make" command

```
make
```

I get this

```
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/accumulators/statistics/stats.hpp:14:
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/accumulators/statistics_fwd.hpp:12:
/opt/local/include/boost/mpl/print.hpp:50:19: warning: in-class initialization
      of non-static data member is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    const int m_x = 1 / (sizeof(T) - sizeof(T));
                  ^
1 warning generated.
mv -f .deps/FRA.Tpo .deps/FRA.Po
/bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++  -g -O2  -L/opt/local/lib -o FRA FRA.o ../../ql/libQuantLib.la -lboost_thread  
libtool: link: g++ -g -O2 -o .libs/FRA FRA.o -Wl,-bind_at_load  -L/opt/local/lib ../../ql/.libs/libQuantLib.dylib -lboost_thread
ld: library not found for -lboost_thread
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [FRA] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: This worked for me: edit `Examples/FRA/Makefile` and replace `-lboost_thread` by `-lboost_thread-mt`. There was only one occurence in the file. Then rerun `make`.

Comment: Now I get this error: ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [quantlib-test-suite] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1